# Drupal - loop all Terms under a Taxonomy

Tags: drupal

Hi
Suppose I have taxonomy "test", and under this taxonomy, I have terms "test2" and "test3". I want to loop all terms under taxonomy "test'. I found a api function "taxonomy_get_children" that can get all children (reference: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_children/6), my code didn't works, could someone give me a idea?(I am using Drupal 6)
Thank you

```
<?php
$a = taxonomy_get_children(1, $vid, 'tid');
print_r($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your tid = 1?  Or is your $vid = 1

tid = term id (the actual term in the vocabulary)
vid = vocab id (the vocabulary where the term exists)

Typically, if you know your vocabulary id is 1, youd call it like this:

```
$a = taxonomy_get_children($tid, 1);
print_r($a);
```

Or if you don't know the vid, just pass in the $tid

```
$a = taxonomy_get_children($tid);
print_r($a);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I use $a = taxonomy_get_children($tid); to pass a vid to the function and it loop all terms that belong to this vocabulary.